# How to add all, except one file in iverilog command line instruction from a folder?

Tags: shell, command-line, verilog, iverilog, icarus

I understand that if I want to include all the Verilog files I can do so by adding files like this:

```
iverilog /Users/kp/Desktop/all_new2/*.v -s testbench.v
```

which takes all files in ***all_new2*** folder and sets ***testbench.v*** as the top module. However, I wish to exclude a file ***c_functions.v*** file from this folder. How do I do it?

Comment: create a file list and use `-ffile` of `-cfile` quals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use the `-y <libdir>` option, which is common among other simulators as well.  This is described in the [iverilog Command Flags/Arguments document](https://iverilog.fandom.com/wiki/Iverilog_Flags).

```
iverilog -y /Users/kp/Desktop/all_new2 testbench.v
```

This will compile only those modules that are needed in the directory.  There is no need to explicitly list out all files.